# Recurrence equation calculation

Tags: recurrence-relation, recursion

I have a recurrece equation

[image]

Changed notations:
$\qquad\displaystyle G(W) = \max \{ G(W - s_i) + v_i \mid 0 \leq i \leq n, w_i \leq W \}$,

I am not sure if I understand $\ w_i $ correctly.

On each iteration my $ w_i \leq W $ . So my $ w_i $ will be previous $ W-s_i $ since G takes one argument?

Comment: All you've given us is a formula. It doesn't consist of a recurrence relation. Also, it's not clear what $G,W,s_i,v_i,w_i$ are, and in particular, it's not clear why $w_i \leq W$ is relevant, since it doesn't appear on the expression being maximized. Have you copied everything correctly?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus you are right I forgot to add the original equation. The equation I inserted earlier was simplified because I did not understand the notations

Comment: It seems that the $w_i$ are additional parameters. There is apparently a typo in the definition: instead of $w_i \le w$, it should be $w_i \le W$.

Comment: The $w_i$, like the $s_i$ and $v_i$, are fixed and do not change during the recurrence.

Comment: Sorry if this question will sound dumb, so $w_i$ is not relevant if I am counting G(W) on i iteration? Or $w_i$ is $ W-s_i $ on i iteration? @YuvalFilmus

Comment: My best guess is that the maximum in the definition of $G(W)$ is taken over all $i$ such that $W \ge w_i$.

Comment: The $w_i$, like the $s_i$ and the $v_i$, are fixed parameters. Each assignment to these parameters gives rise to a function $G$ defined recursively.

Comment: What misleads me is that $w_i$ is not defined in array as $ V $ and $ S $, so how can it be fixed parameter?

Comment: I would guess that $W$ consists of $w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n$, just like $V$ and $S$. The argument to $G$ should be $w$ rather than $W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is pseudocode for computing your function:

> Parameters:
>
> - Integer $n$
> - Arrays $W,V,S$ of length $n$
>
> function G(w):
>
> - If $w = 0$, return $0$
> - Let $\mathrm{max} \gets -\infty$
> - For $i$ from $1$ to $n$:
> - - If $W[i] \leq w$:
> - - - Let $x \gets G(w-S[i])+V[i]$
> - - - If $x > \mathrm{max}$, let $\mathrm{max} \gets x$
> - Return $\mathrm{max}$

I used the notation $W[i],V[i],S[i]$ rather than $w_i,v_i,s_i$.